# Apple Indoor Map?

Tags: ios, indoor-positioning-system

I would like to make a map of my school that can provide directions and the user's location through an apple app. What would be the best way to go about doing this? I found apple's indoor maps service, but I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to go about it, and all the examples I have seen only use google's maps. Also, I don't know if apple's indoor maps system handles multiple floors (I would assume so, but haven;t yet seen any evidence). Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would look into using Beacons. There are proprietary ones that provide an SDK, or you could just use the iBeacon SDK that is a part of CoreLocationServices. You can also handle multiple floors with this approach. They communicate using Bluetooth Low Energy signals and are accurate down to around a meter distance wise. Here are a couple companies that make them:

http://estimote.com/
http://gimbal.com/

Comment: +1 for using beacons. GPS is just too unreliable indoors. Apple now allows you to serve up custom map data as an option, so you could build custom maps of your indoor location (although this is a lot of work. Take a look at the MKTileOverlay class for more info.) I'm not aware of any facility for handling multiple floors with different floor-plans in Apple's map system though.